# How to include non-pydantic classes in fastapi responses?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to include a custom class into a route's response. I'm mostly using nested `pydantic.BaseModel`s in my application, so it would be nice to return the whole thing without writing a translation from the internal data representation to what the route returns.

As long as *everything* inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel` this is trivial, but I'm using a class `Foo` in my backend which can't do that, and I can't subclass it for this purpose either. Can I somehow duck type that class's definition in a way that `fastapi` accepts it? What I have right now is essentially this:

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Foo:
    """Foo holds data and can't inherit from `pydantic.BaseModel`."""
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x


class Response(BaseModel):
    foo: Foo
    # plus some more stuff that doesn't matter right now because it works


@app.get("/", response_model=Response)
def root():
    return Response(foo=Foo(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("main:app")  # RuntimeError
```

Comment: You could use `BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True` - [see fastapi issue 2382](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2382#issuecomment-865635415)

Comment: Doing that leads to a valid pydantic class, but you'll still get runtime errors both when trying to get a response as well when trying to render the OpenAPI pages, because fastapi doesn't know how to turn a `Foo` instance into json. And since you need to add validators to do that, when you're done you don't need to allow arbitrary types any more because then it's well defined.

Comment: Actually, the server won't even start: `fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class '__main__.Foo'> is a valid pydantic field type`

Comment: Declared global in the main app file (`BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True`) the server starts fine for me and returns `foo: x: 1`(minimal example on localhost) - the API definition fails for me as well.. - I just commented because I stumbled over the issue which seems to talk about the same problem...

Comment: You're right, I wonder why setting arbitrary types globally is so different from setting it on the `Response` class. I'll simplify my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not documented, but you can make non-`pydantic` classes work with `fastapi`. What you need to do is:

1. Tell `pydantic` that using arbitrary classes is fine. It
   will try to jsonify them using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), so only straight forward
   data containers will work - no using `property`, `__slots__` or stuff like that<sup>[1]</sup>.
2. Create a proxy `BaseModel`, and tell `Foo` to offer it if someone
   asks for its schema - which is what `fastapi`s OpenAPI pages do.
   I'll just assume that you want them to work too since they're
   amazing.

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseConfig, create_model

app = FastAPI()
BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True  # change #1


class Foo:
    """Foo holds data and can't inherit from `pydantic.BaseModel`."""    
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    __pydantic_model__ = create_model("Foo", x=(int, ...))  # change #2


class Response(BaseModel):
    foo: Foo


@app.get("/", response_model=Response)
def root():
    return Response(foo=Foo(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("main:app")  # works
```

---

<sup>[1] <sub>If you want more complex jsonification, you need to provide it to the `Response` class explicitly via [`Config.json_encoders`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders).</sub></sup>

Comment: can you please help with example of Config.json_encoders usage. For example if type was `psycopg2.extras.DateTimeTZRange`

Comment: It worked even with non-basic types. Thank you

Comment: In fact, only this line was enough: `BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True`

Comment: If you wind up on this answer, you probably need to simply enable the ORM mode, and map your Pydantic classes to the ORM classes: https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full implementation using a subclass with validators and extra schema:

```py
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange as DateTimeTZRangeBase
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TSTZRANGE
from sqlmodel import (
    Column,
    Field,
    Identity,
    SQLModel,
)

from pydantic.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE

ENCODERS_BY_TYPE |= {DateTimeTZRangeBase: str}


class DateTimeTZRange(DateTimeTZRangeBase):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            lower = v.split(", ")[0][1:].strip().strip()
            upper = v.split(", ")[1][:-1].strip().strip()
            bounds = v[:1] + v[-1:]
            return DateTimeTZRange(lower, upper, bounds)
        elif isinstance(v, DateTimeTZRangeBase):
            return v
        raise TypeError("Type must be string or DateTimeTZRange")

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string", example="[2022,01,01, 2022,02,02)")


class EventBase(SQLModel):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    timestamp_range: DateTimeTZRange = Field(
        sa_column=Column(
            TSTZRANGE(),
            nullable=False,
        ),
    )


class Event(EventBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(
        default=None,
        sa_column_args=(Identity(always=True),),
        primary_key=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
```

as per @Arne 's solution you need to add your own validators and schema if the Type you are using has `__slots__` and basically no way to get out a `dict`.

Link to Github issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/235#issuecomment-1162063590